# Can't run a basic Typescript script through a .net core web app

Tags: typescript, gulp, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, browserify

Project struct

```
Proj
--wwwroot/scripts
--scripts
--tsconfig.json
----Account
------app.ts
--gulpfile.js
```

Given the following TypeScript in scripts/Account/app.ts:

```
function sayHello() {
    alert('hello world');
}
```

a tsconfig.json file of

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6", 
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ] 
  },
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

and a gulpfile.js of

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var tsify = require('tsify');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: '.',                               
        entries: ['scripts/Account/app.ts'],        
        cache: {},                                  
        packageCache: {}                           
        })
        .plugin(tsify)                              
        .bundle()                                   
        .pipe(source('scripts/Account/app.js'))             
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/scripts"));        
});
```

I get an outputted file in wwwroot/scripts/app.js.  But the function can't be called from the web pages that use it because it isn't available globally as it appears to be wrapped in a function:

[image: Screenshot]

So what am I missing in my compilation steps to be able to call a basic typescript function?  I've tried exporting the function, in which case it just adds it to the exports object:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Configuration** : Specify a name to be used as [standalone lib](https://github.com/browserify/browserify#usage)

```js
gulp.task('default', function () {
    return browserify({
            basedir: '.',                               
            entries: ['scripts/Account/app.ts'],        
            cache: {},                                  
            packageCache: {},
            standalone : "XLib",        // specify a name to be used as standalone lib
        })
        .plugin(tsify)                              
        .bundle()                                   
        .pipe(source('scripts/Account/app.js'))             
        .pipe(gulp.dest("wwwroot/scripts"));        
});
```

**Expose the function** :

```js
export function sayHello() {
    alert('hello world');
}
```

**Consume the library in browser**:

```html
<script>
    XLib.sayHello();
</script>
```

**Demo** :

[image]